# Sync colours between Google Calendar apps

Tags: google-calendar

So I've set up sync between the Google Calendar app on my phone (which syncs events correctly). I am talking about the official app here, not some alternate default app. However, the colours seen on the Google Calendar website are quite different. In fact, even the colour names options are very different (e.g. orange,red vs tangerine,flamingo). Is it possible to fix this?
[image: desktop Calendar website]
[image: mobile Calendar app]